# Search automatically for Rss Feed

Tags: c#, rss

I want to create an application in C#, specifically a windows form application. I want, for example, a text field where I enter a URL for a website (not a URL for feeds). Then I want my application to search automatically for Feeds on that web site. I then want to display a message about if any exist or not. How can I do that?

Comment: I do not have anything for now. I keep searching on internet about this because I don't know how to begin. My application, for now just use a URL RSS feed instead a URL website - first page and retrive data from that url rss feed. Now I want to put only the url website and I want that my application to search for Rss on that website and then give me a message .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search for information in the html code of the site.

```
<head>
  ...
  <link ... type="application/rss+xml" .../>
  <link ... type="application/atom+xml" .../>
  ...
</head>
```

For example you can download the html file with a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.DownloadFile(your uri, local filepath);
```

Then read the file and search for your RSS:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(local filepath);

if(s.IndexOf("type=\"application/rss+xml\"") != -1)//found
  MessageBox.Show("found rss");
```

Comment: The OP wants to implement this in C# so the answer should include  an C# code that approximates the problem (regardless of the quality of the question).

Comment: i added some code. thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks fedab. I'll try like you said. I think it'll work like that.